# Why does the behavior differ between VB.net and C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

As for as I can tell the following two example are the same in terms of functionality.

C#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   var x = new Example(12);
   var y = new Example(34);
   var z = Example.Examples.One;
  }
 }
 class Example
 {
  public static class Examples
  {
   public static readonly Example Zero = new Example(0);
   public static readonly Example One = new Example(1);
  }
  public readonly Double Value;
  public Example(Double Value)
  {
   this.Value = Value;
  }
  public static Example Add(Example x, Example y)
  {
   return new Example(x.Value + y.Value);
  }
 }
}
```

VB.net

```
Option Strict On
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

    Dim x=New Example(12)
    Dim y = New Example(34)
    Dim z=  Example.Examples.One
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Example

  Public  Class Examples
    Public Shared ReadOnly Zero As Example
    Public Shared ReadOnly One As Example
    Public Shared ReadOnly Two As Example
    Public Shared ReadOnly MinusOne As Example
    Shared Sub new()
      Zero=New Example(0)
      One= New Example(1)
      Two = New Example(2)
      MinusOne = New Example(-1)
    End Sub
  End Class
  Public ReadOnly Value As Double
  Public Sub New(Value As Double)
    Me.Value=Value
  End Sub
  Public Shared Function Add(x As Example,y As Example) As Example
    Return New Example(x.Value+y.Value)
  End Function
End Class
```

So why do I get only the instance methods in C# after the dot (see below)

```
z = Example.Examples.One.
```

and in VB.net

```
Dim z = Example.Examples.One.
```

I also get the `Examples`

What is going on? Why the difference?

Comment: Is this a question about runtime behavior or Visual Studio Intellisense?

Comment: I think Slaks guessed right but the question fails to make the point. It's also way too long.

Comment: @Kal_Torak It could be either, since I don't know why. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Henk Holterman
Way too long? I provided two code examples in different language, so users can replicate the code I have and see the "issue" I'm experiencing. 

Stack Overflow can't have it both ways.
 Question Too Short,
 Question Too Long,
 No Code Provided.


**(And why doesn't the comments preserve the line breaks, you can enter into the writable version on the comments. But removes them when you save them.)**

Comment: @HenkHolterman As far as I can tell, Adam is more or less following SO's [MVCE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have a few recommendations: 1) I'd recommend making it clear that you are getting a compiler error on `var z = Example.Examples.One;`, 2) Please add `<!-- language: lang-vb -->`, followed by a newline before the VB.NET code block to make syntax highlighting work, 3) your indentation in the VB.NET sample is inconsistent 4) (these last two are probably more of a matter of personal style) I find the one space indenting on the C# snippet very hard to read, 5) I'd recommend adding more newlines to your code in both samples, e.g., after `End Sub`

Comment: Also I think you've ran into [another weird VB.NET "feature"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47814420/4975230), I think it would be cool to hear Microsoft's reasoning on why some of these quirks were added but I get the feeling that the VB.NET team isn't as active on SO as the C# team.

Answer (score 6):

For compatibility reasons, VB.Net alows you to access `Shared` (`static`) methods through an instance qualifier.
Don't do it; it's confusing.

Comment: Yes I know it's confusing. 
Could anyone provide an example of the compatibility, cos as I remember in vb6 you could not define classes.

Comment: In VB6 you could define classes - they were contained in .cls files.

Comment: It's also 20 years old. WHAT IS THIS MYTHICAL COMPATIBILITY people keep mentioning. Provide links to documentation I can look at and research.  I don't think I even own a machine that can run the vb6 IDE now.

Comment: +1. But this isn't for compatibility reasons. VB6 didn't allow Shared (static) methods on classes at all. @Adam here is the [VB6 reference guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032(v=VS.60).aspx). And the VB6 IDE works on Win7 64 bit. And VB6 is 15 years old (released 1998).

Comment: @MarkJ Thank you for the resource link. VB first appeared in 1991 (thus 21 years old). It was SLaks who said it was for compatibility. I'm trying to ascertain what that compatibility reason was.