# Why are late bound method calls designed to only work on public methods?

Tags: vb.net, late-binding

#### About the limitation

As per Microsoft's [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/), late binding only works on public methods.

> Late binding can only be used to access type members that are declared as Public. Accessing members declared as Friend or Protected Friend results in a run-time error.

I've been curious as to why this restriction was put in.

It seems a bit strange from a language design perspective that early binding respects access rights for methods, but late binding only supports `public` methods.

---

#### Example showing the limitation

Here's a VB.NET MVCE, it demonstrates the limitation.

```vb
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off

Class SomeClass
    Public Sub PublicMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("SomePublicMethod")
    End Sub

    Friend Sub InternalMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("InternalMethod")
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrivateMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("PrivateMethod")
    End Sub

    'Note Late binding can only be used to access type members that are declared as Public. Accessing members
    'declared as Friend Or Protected Friend results in a runtime error.


    Public Sub Test()
        Dim classInstance As New SomeClass
        Dim classInstanceObj As Object = classInstance

        'Early binding. All of these work.
        classInstance.PublicMethod()
        classInstance.InternalMethod()
        classInstance.PrivateMethod()

        'Now for late binding

        'Runs okay.
        classInstanceObj.PublicMethod()

        'Both of these fail (MissingMemberException), even though technically it turns out that
        'this class has access to them.
        classInstanceObj.InternalMethod()
        classInstanceObj.PrivateMethod()

    End Sub

End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim testInstance As New SomeClass()
        testInstance.Test()

    End Sub

End Module
```

---

#### For fun, let's look at the implementation.

The call stack of the resulting exception looks like this:

```vb
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(String& MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.CallMethod(Container BaseReference, String MethodName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags InvocationFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at PublicLateBinding.SomeClass.Test() in <PathToModule1.vb>\Module1.vb:line 39
```

Unfortunately, Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll is still mostly closed source, so I'll have to rely on DotPeek for this one.

I'm going to take a guess and say that `LookupDefaultMembers` in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container` is responsible for collecting runnable member methods. Its decompiled code looks like this (sorry, DotPeek can only decompile to C#).

**Decompiled implementation code from Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll:**

```cs
private MemberInfo[] LookupDefaultMembers(ref string DefaultMemberName, Type SearchType)
{
    string name = (string) null;
    Type Type = SearchType;
    do
    {
        object[] customAttributes = Type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DefaultMemberAttribute), false);

        if (customAttributes != null && customAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            name = ((DefaultMemberAttribute) customAttributes[0]).MemberName;
            break;
        }
        Type = Type.BaseType;
    }
    while ((object) Type != null && !Symbols.IsRootObjectType(Type));
    MemberInfo[] memberInfoArray1;
    if (name != null)
    {
      MemberInfo[] memberInfoArray2 = Symbols.Container.FilterInvalidMembers(Type.GetMember(name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy));
      if (memberInfoArray2 != null)
      {
        DefaultMemberName = name;
        if (memberInfoArray2.Length > 1)
        {
            Array.Sort((Array) memberInfoArray2, (IComparer) Symbols.Container.InheritanceSorter.Instance);
        }
        memberInfoArray1 = memberInfoArray2;
        goto label_10;
      }
    }
    memberInfoArray1 = Symbols.Container.NoMembers;
    label_10:
    return memberInfoArray1;
}
```

I'd like to specifically emphasize this part:

> Type.GetMember(name, **BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy**);

It appears that this was a deliberate move, to not pass [`GetMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dk6tw7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, among others. Though, the fact that `BindingFlags.Static` is included is interesting...

---

#### I'll take a couple guesses as to why it's like this:

(to the best of my knowledge, there isn't any official statement from Microsoft on this)

1. It was not worth the effort to make a version of the reflection methods that support enforcing access rights (i.e., something that would check the method flags / assemblies, and throw an exception if and only if the late bound object really can't run the method, based on the access level of the method).
2. This is some kind of backwards compatibility thing, e.g,. VB6 only allowed late binding on `Public` methods and this was done to make automatic code conversion easier? (I haven't done any VB6/VBA/VBScript/anything else VB)
3. Having late binding only on `Public` methods was easier to explain and document, instead of writing "Late binding only works if you are following the access level of the method".

---

I figured it was alright to post this because C# gets questions like ["What was the design rationale for making void not a primitive type?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854117/what-was-the-design-rationale-for-making-void-not-a-primitive-type), unfortunately there seems to be a lack of questions like this for VB.NET, hopefully this is well received.

Comment: Note: If you would prefer decompiled VB.NET source, I am willing to hand translate it to VB.NET, just leave me a comment.

Comment: It was designed as a substitute for early-binding and not designed to be a back-door that would allow you access methods that the programmer intentionally meant for you to not access.  The accessibility rules used in early-binding apply here as well.  If you want to color outside of those lines then you have to use reflection so you can pass BindingFlags.NonPublic.

Comment: @HansPassant makes sense, hypothetically would it have been possible to make reflection functions that were smart enough to allow, for example, late bound `Friend` method calls to objects as long as they were within the assembly?

Comment: Implicit in late-binding is that the code lives in an assembly that you know little about and isn't yours.  Because it you would then you'd never use it.

Comment: @HansPassant I can see your point about how it's commonly used (i.e., to access unknown interfaces, e.g. COM stuff), I was mostly curious because it seems a bit less than rigorous from a language design point of view, that a late bound method call would not follow the same access rights as a non-late bound method call. Feel free to post something like your comments as an answer, I found them helpful.